# Trying to publish a website on github I don't know where to start

Tags: github, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to publish a webpage through github. Can anyone give me steps on how to do this correctly. I have a repository on github but I have been unsuccessful with it being published through github.

Comment: When you say *"unsuccessful"* it's more helpful to give a [mcve] illustrating what you've tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead. Did you [read the docs](https://pages.github.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

**Create your repository on git through**

```
username.github.io
```

They have a very detailed guide here:
https://pages.github.com/